# Determining if a found string is contained within a hyperlink using xpath or regex (or other)

Tags: python, regex, xpath, web-scraping, lxml

On a page such as [this](http://british-business-bank.co.uk/what-the-british-business-bank-does/job-vacancies/), the individual jobs are outlined behind hyperlinks (but my program does not yet know this; all it knows is that it has arrived at a jobs listings page).

Given a search term e.g. 'senior project manager', I scrape the source of the page to determine if the page contains this string;

```
search_term = 'senior project manager'
url = 'http://british-business-bank.co.uk/what-the-british-business-bank-does/job-vacancies/'
source = urllib2.urlopen(url).read().lower()
found_a_match = search_term in source
```

In this case, with `search_term` **True**, I then want to determine if the full job description is behind a hyperlink. Manual inspection of the source shows:

```
<p><a href="http://british-business-bank.co.uk/?p=6419">Senior Project Manager &#8211; Northern Powerhouse Investment Fund</a></p>
```

I guess I could parse the source again, this time looking for a match for *the search term preceded by an `<a>`*, but I have a (perhaps unfounded) feeling that this may be a little brittle. What is a more robust approach?

**NOTE:** I know I can look into *BeautifulSoup*, *lxml*, *scrapy* et al to achieve this, but given that speed is of the essence and that there will be little if any more parsing to de done once I've made this hyperlink-or-not determination, I'm looking to keep things simple.

Comment: In my opinion, parsing the HTML and applying an XPath expression will not be overhead, it will be exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to build a solution that would ignore any matches within `<a></a>` tags. My approach was as follows:

In a pre-processing pass, search and record the positions of all `<a.*>` and `</a>` strings -- I used an array where each entry contains a start and stop position, for `<a>` and `</a>`, respectively.

Then when your searching for matches, determining whether a match is within hyperlink tags is a simple matter of running through the list of tags' start/stop positions and see if the match's offset is within any of those.